# Android Eclipse Resources refresh/caching problem

Tags: android, eclipse, caching, deployment, apk

I try to develop my first Android app with Eclipse and the Android maven plugin. If I build and deploy my app to a virutal device for the first time, everything works fine. But if I change a layout, I got strange NullPointerExceptions on running the app again. Some Views are not find or I got a class cast exception, because the views I search by id are of the wrong type. So I have to rename same views and build again. After that it works. That ist a strange caching/recompile behavior. If i juist build and deploy my *.apk with maven, it works everytime. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've faced something similar from time to time. This seems to happen when I've saved changes to both code and layout within one 'save all'. You can get around it by selecting "Project / Clean..." from the main menu, it'll recompile your project and this has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At times i face this issue with eclipse or RSA[rational software architect].Use project->clean to compile and build, even in the case you selected "Build Automatically". This works most of the times.